# How to debug uncalled __del__()

Tags: python, destructor, del

I use `__del__()` to write a warning log in case the object gets deleted while in a wrong internal state (please no wrath about it).

I tried to test it but although I use `del my_object` in the test, the `__del__()` doesn't seem to be called.

[`__del__()`'s reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) warns of 3 situations where this might happen, but doesn't give a clue on how to debug them.

So... How do I go about debugging it?

Comment: @agf - yes, how? (besides going through a lot of code of course)

Comment: you should give us some code.

Comment: It's simple. Don't use `__del__`, use context managers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `__del__` is not being called when you invoke `del myObject` directly, then there is at least one other outstanding reference to myObject. I'm guessing you have stuffed it into a list or dict or set (or perhaps a memoizing cache), which does *not* copy the object, just saves a second reference to the original.  Even doing:

```
myObject = MyObjectClassWith__del__()
del myObject
```

might not necessarily call `__del__`, if the class's `__init__` method or `__new__` method saves the new instance into some class-level cache or structure.

Bottom line: check for other references, either by inspecting your code, or by using the weakref or gc methods posted in other answers.

Answer (score 4):

You can change all references between the suspect objects to [weakref](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html) and watch the output of the callback you provide to `weakref.ref`

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can try to force [gc to collect](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.collect) the object.  If you want to find out what objects still have references to your objects and might be keeping them from being garbage collected, play around with [`gc.get_referrers`](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers) and [`gc.get_referents`](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.get_referents).

Comment: The `gc` module does not collect objects that have a `__del__` method, so calling `gc.collect()` is not going to collect it. All it _may_ do is land the object in `gc.garbage`.